# Double showing int value

Tags: c++, double

I don' t understand why when i use the function in main( Serie(1), Serie(n) ), it keeps showing the result "1", although it is a double value.

```
double Serie(int n)
{
    double sum = 0;

    for(int i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + (1/i);
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As already noted, you are using integer division in the expression `1/i`, and the result of this will therefore be 0 for `i > 1`. An easy solution is to change:

```
    sum = sum + (1/i);
```

to:

```
    sum = sum + 1.0 / i;
```

or perhaps more succinctly:

```
    sum += 1.0 / i;
```

Answer (score 3):

`(1/i)` is not a `double` value. `1` is an integer literal, `i` is an `int`, so `1/i` performs an integer division.

When the `double` type `sum` comes into the equation, it's already too late for you.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `(1/i)` is an integer division. The first time through it'll evaluate to `(1/1)` giving you 1. When you add it to `sum` there will be an integer promotion to double.

However, on all subsequent occasions (eg `(1/2)`, `(1/3)` etc) your integer division will yield `0`. You'll then integer promote this to a double and add it to `sum` which won't change it.

To fix this say `(1/(double)i)` or `(1.0/i)` to force the division to yield a `double`.

Answer (score 0):

As your operation (1/i) contains both values as integer(i in this case is integer). This part of the expression results in integer result. Decimals get truncated in this case.

To get the double result you can typecast either 1 or i to double.